# What is a simple SQL query to select the ID of a person with the SECOND highest salary

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I had a relation: employee(id, salary). What would be the simplest SQL query to select the ID of the person with the second highest salary.

I know how to select the highest salary using:

```
SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM employee
WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary)
FROM employee);
```

but how would you select the ID of that person, and display only the ID of the person with the second highest salary (without using LIMIT).

Comment: psql is usually associated with Postgres, so I added the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` or `rank()`, depending on what you mean by second highest salary:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) as seqnum
      FROM employee e
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 2;
```

If you want to use your query -- and this seems way more complicated -- you can use subqueries:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employee e
WHERE e.salary = (SELECT MAX(e2.salary)
                  FROM employee e2
                  WHERE e2.salary < (SELECT MAX(e3.salary)
                                     FROM employee e3
                                    )
                 );
```

It is nice to see that SQL has made some progress in the last 30 years.

Answer (score 3):

The optimal answer depends on the existence of an index on salary. I have setup a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3eafe/3) which loads 100k rows in a table.

With an index, my answer would be:

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

This is the simplest, shortest and cleanest one. It is also the fastest, at 40µs, as it uses an Index Scan Backwards. However, if there is a tie-in for second position, it will only return one row.

Still with an index, the three above queries with max() in subqueries are a close second. Bob Jarvis' scores 100µs.

Unfortunately, Gordon's window function hits a snag as postgres scans the entire index (well, at least it does not do a sort):

```
Subquery Scan on e (cost=0.29..7518.27 rows=500 width=20) (actual time=0.042..137.810 rows=1 loops=1)
Filter: (e.seqnum = 2)
Rows Removed by Filter: 99999
-> WindowAgg (cost=0.29..6268.27 rows=100000 width=20) (actual time=0.029..121.445 rows=100000 loops=1)
-> Index Scan Backward using emps_sal on employee e_1 (cost=0.29..4768.27 rows=100000 width=12)
 (actual time=0.022..54.861 rows=100000 loops=1)
```

This takes 137ms which is quite long. I believe the root cause to be that postgres treats "seqnum=2" as any other WHERE expression and thus does not realize it could stop after the second row. We can nudge it by adding a "LIMIT 1" in which case it does stop after the second row, and takes only 70µs, so it is very fast.

**Now, without an index...**

My query with the ORDER BY does a sort, however it is postgres' glorious top-n heapsort which is fast: 34ms.

Gordon't window function does a full sort, which takes 108ms.

Bob's query does not sort, but it scans the table 3 times: 84 ms.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE salary = (
  SELECT max(salary)
  FROM employee
  WHERE salary != (
    SELECT max(salary)
    FROM employee
  )
);
```

Comment: . . The Chinese didn't help the answer.  You might want to rephrase it in English.

Comment: But my English is not familiar with, can only use Google translation...

Comment: . . That is probably okay.  The Chinese is not appropriate on an English-only web site.

Comment: Okay, it's my fault. The The    ╮ (╯ ▽ ╰) ╭

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID
  FROM EMPLOYEE
  WHERE SALARY = (SELECT MAX(salary) AS SECOND_HIGHEST_SALARY
                    FROM employee
                    WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) AS HIGHEST_SALARY
                                      FROM employee)
```

This will give you the IDs of all employees who have the second-highest salary. If you only want one employee use `SELECT MIN(ID)` on the outer query.